# Taylor expansion of multivariable function (inner product notation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, taylor-expansion

For $f \in \mathcal C^2 (\mathbb R^n ; \mathbb R)\;$ my professor suggested the following Taylor expansion :

$f(x)=f(a)+ \nabla f(a)(x-a)\;+\;\frac{1}{2} \left\langle {\partial}^2 f(a) (x-a), (x-a)\right\rangle\;+o({\vert x-a \vert}^2)\;$

where $\langle .,.\rangle$ is an inner product.

I cannot understand the second-order part of the expansion. I know that it holds:

$$\;f(x)=f(a)+\nabla f(a)\cdot (x-a)+{1\over2}\sum_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\left({\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right)_a (x_i-a)(x_j-a)\;$$

but it's a bit unclear to me the connection between these two. What am I missing?

Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Remember that $\partial ^2 f$ is to be interpreted as a matrix of second order partial derivatives.

Comment: Maybe if $ {\partial}^2 f(a)$ is the Hessian matrix the two expressions coincide.

Comment: @N74 Well yes it's the hessian.. of course they coincide. Silly question I made!